# How to create and display the MainWindow outside the Main()?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've made LONG research on the web but can't find anything clear.
I think the answer is obvious but i'm beginer in Qt.
Why this code doesn't work ? My windows just popup realy fast.

Main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
Test test;

return a.exec();
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

Test::Test()
{
 MainWindow w;
 w.show();
}
```

And this one work (the window keep open) :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Its about scope. Your window no longer exists in your first example (after the constructor finishes) while the scope in the second example is as long as main().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window closes because it is local variable of the Test constructor, and when the constructor exits, its destructor gets called, which closes it. You need to make the window object a member variable of the Test class.